# if else statement not working properly unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

```cs
void OnTriggerStay(Collider player)
    {
        if (player.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
             if (Input.GetKeyDown("g")) //If G is pressed
                 {
                      if (!G1.activeInHierarchy)
                         {
                             G1.SetActive(true);    
                         }
                      else if (G1.activeInHierarchy)
                         {
                             G1.SetActive(false);
                            G2.SetActive(true);
                         }
  
                 }
        }
    }
```

When running this code and clicking G button.
It activates both G1 and G2.
But it should be G1 first then after clicking the G button again then it should open G2.

Comment: You should probably use the new input system

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `else` statement can never happen. There cannot be a scenario where a boolean in something other than `true` or `false`, which you have covered in your `if` & `else if`

Secondly, your logic can be simplified. You coder states that you want the following behaviour:

- if G1 is active, deactivate it. And if it is deactivated, activate it - which means we can just toggle the active every time
- if G1 is active, we want to make G2 active - which means we need an if statement to activate G2
- The else-statement is never executed and can be deleted

```cs
if (Input.GetKeyDown("g"))
{
    if (G1.activeInHierarchy)
    {
        G2.SetActive(true);
    }
    
    G1.SetActive(!G1.activeInHierarchy);
}
```

---

### Now, to answer your question

There might be many reasons. Perhaps this script is attached to many components, so it is executed many times? That would explain why both get activated since the logic is currently:

G -> G1 active
G -> G1 inactive, G2 active
G -> G1 active, G2 still active

If you wish to deactivate G2 on the third click, you need to do `G2.SetActive(false)` when you activate G1.

---

If you want a behaviour where clicking G toggles between two gameobjects, you can simply do...

```cs
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
{
    G1.SetActive(!G1.activeInHierarch);
    G2.SetActive(!G2.activeInHierarch);
}
```

given that one of them is active from the start, it will produce this behaviour:

G1: active
G2. inactive

> CLICK G

G1: inactive
G2: active

> CLICK G

G1: active
G2: inactive

... etc

---

To get your desired behaviour with minimal changes to your code, simply move the else-code to the first if:

```cs
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
{
    if (!G1.activeInHierarchy)
    {
        G1.SetActive(true);
        G2.SetActive(false);
    }
    else if (G1.activeInHierarchy)
    {
        G1.SetActive(false);
        G2.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Which of course can be simplified to...

```cs
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
{
    G1.SetActive(!G1.activeInHierarchy);
    G2.SetActive(G1.activeInHierarchy);
}
```

Comment: I think there might be a state missing.. to me it looks like the states OP is after would be `G1 active`, `G2 active` and `None active` .. but from the description I am also confused about that tbh ^^

Comment: Hi Fredrik, I tried this line of code:
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
{
    G1.SetActive(!G1.activeInHierarchy);
    G2.SetActive(G1.activeInHierarchy);
}
But now the effect is it opens both then closes it again.
This line of code is under onntriggerstay. maybe it is the cause?

Comment: void OnTriggerStay(Collider player)
    {
        if (player.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            

            if (Input.GetKeyDown("g")) //If G is pressed
            {


                if (!G1.activeInHierarchy)
                {
                    G1.SetActive(true);
                    G2.SetActive(false);
                }
                else if (G1.activeInHierarchy)
                {
                    G1.SetActive(false);
                    G2.SetActive(true);
                }
                

            }
            
  
        }
    }

Comment: OnTriggerStay is called around 60 times per second as long as an object is within that trigger